# How does article deletion work in phrases like "both a hot weather and cold"? Is that allowed?

Tags: articles, ellipsis

Consider the self-made sentence below

> They assessed the durability for the ***both a hot weather and cold***.

Is ***both a hot weather and cold*** correct?

I don't know if I can omit the indefinite article  as above.

---

I didn't notice that I was using an unidiomatic collocation for "a + adjective + uncountable noun" pattern, but as @Jason noticed it my point was something else. Thanks for correcting that issue anyways.

Comment: This sentence does not really make much sense. A corrected sentence would be "They assessed the durability for both hot and cold weather" OR "The assessed the durability for both hot weather and cold weather" ... That being said I am not sure where that leaves your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific sentence in the question doesn't really make sense—it shouldn't have an indefinite article in the first place. (The definite article should also not be there.)

A better version would be:

> ✔ They assessed its durability in both hot weather and cold.

Although the indefinite article no longer applies, the second instance of *weather* can be omitted.

---

Here is a different sentence of the same type that uses the indefinite article:

> ✔ They ate a meal both hot and cold.

The syntax allows for an indefinite article. But note that it doesn't follow the *exact* construction of the sentence in the question. (The indefinite article comes before *both* rather than after it.) It's referring to a single meal that is both hot and cold rather than to one meal that is hot and another meal that is cold.

---

Finally, here is a construction that is identical to the one in the question:

> ✔ They ate both a hot meal and a cold meal.
>   → They ate both a hot meal and <s>a</s> cold <s>meal</s>.
>   → They ate both a hot meal and cold.

I'm fairly sure that it's *syntactically* sound to omit the words that have been omitted. Since it's a parallel construction, the reader should be able to mentally replace them and understand the meaning.

However, these particular omissions seem a little awkward. At least *stylistically*, I suspect the omissions would not normally take place.

Comment: Thank you Jason, I am really happy that you could understand my major concern about that question. So you think, a native writer would be more likely to use a different structure than doing that omissions, right?

Comment: @Cardinal Right. I think that in this specific case (the last construction in my answer), there would normally not be an omission.

Answer (score 1):

"Weather" is not a countable noun and so never takes an indefinite article.

So the proper phrasing is either

> both hot and cold weather

or

> both hot weather and cold weather

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I know that  I shouldn't use an indefinite article right before an uncountable noun. No doubt 100 percent, but the thing is the article here is before the adjective not the noun. That a hot weather is not an idiomatic collocation is something different IMHO.

Comment: The rules about articles and uncountable nouns are not affected by whether the noun is modified by an adjectve. But you may be making a more subtle point, namely that, In many respects, "hot weather" and "cold weather" **are** treated as a single two-word noun rather than as an adjective plus a noun. That is, they are considered different things rather than different aspects of the same thing. But even if that is so, both nouns are uncountable.